# Asp.Net Membership per request change applicationname

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

We have one application that runs off of one DB but has multiple domains pointing to it and depending on the domain determines which css we load and which customers data is displayed.  Everything works fine except I would like to change the application name of the SqlMembership provider per request depending on which customer it is to ensure no conflicts between usernames/emails in the membership provider.

So if the domain is abc123.com I want to change the ApplicationName just for that request.  Unfortunately the Membership is static per application so my question is how do I go about this.  Ideally I would like to just instantiate a SqlMembershipProvider, RoleProvider, ProfileProvider on the base controller we have from what is in the web.config and change just the application name at the start of the request without effecting any other requests.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

**EDIT:**

OK at the moment I am trying this, I have a base controller and within the override for OnActionExecuting I am building a SqlMembershipProvider and calling Initialize with the NameValueCollection containing all the properties I need and altering the ApplicationName depending on the customer (which is known by the url).

Does anyone see any problems with this?

**EDIT:**
Nope that doesn't work either, it's still trying to load form the web.config with certain methods so ValidateUser works but CreateUser throw an exception as it cannot find the entry in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in the root web.config.
Add an applicationname attribute to the nodes where you define the different providers.
Just make sure to use a different name for each app.

```
add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="YourAppName" />
```

Comment: The trouble is we already have 20 sites running and are aiming for 100's, I don't want to have to put that much info in the web.config as the only property we want to change is the application name and everything else will be the same.